# Sql Pivot table with three cross tab and multiple columns dynamically

Tags: sql, pivot

I have the following table with values as

```
CREATE TABLE stud 
  ( 
     sname NVARCHAR(10), 
     hr    NVARCHAR(30), 
     dt    DATETIME, 
     att   VARCHAR(3) 
  )

INSERT INTO stud VALUES ('Abi',  '1',  '21/01/2013','a')
INSERT INTO stud VALUES ('Abi',  '2',  '21/01/2013','p')
INSERT INTO stud VALUES ('bala',  '1',  '21/01/2013','p')
INSERT INTO stud VALUES ('bala',  '2',  '21/01/2013','a')
INSERT INTO stud VALUES ('bala',  '1',  '22/01/2013','od')
INSERT INTO stud VALUES ('bala',  '2',  '22/01/2013','ml')
INSERT INTO stud VALUES ('Abi',  '1',  '22/01/2013','ml')
INSERT INTO stud VALUES ('Abi',  '2',  '22/01/2013','od')
```

If i select this table i get the output as

```
SELECT * 
FROM   stud
```

```
sname   hr            dt                att
Abi 1   2013-01-21 00:00:00.000  a
Abi 2   2013-01-21 00:00:00.000  p
bala    1   2013-01-21 00:00:00.000  p
bala    2   2013-01-21 00:00:00.000  a
bala    1   2013-01-22 00:00:00.000  od
bala    2   2013-01-22 00:00:00.000  ml
Abi 1   2013-01-22 00:00:00.000  ml
Abi 2   2013-01-22 00:00:00.000  od
```

but I want the output as follows in crystal report in ASP.NET ( Note : the date should given as dynamically as **from_date** to **to to_date** )

[image]

`sname          21/01/2013              22/01/2013`

I tried for this output from long days itself, but didn't get output.

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: @bluefeet I would have to guess MSSQL from `NVARCHAR`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+, then there are several ways that you can apply the `PIVOT` function.

You can hard-code the values in the form of a static pivot:

```
select *
from
(
  select sname, 
    'hour_no_'+hr+'_'+convert(nvarchar(10), dt, 120) dt,
    att
  from stud
) st
pivot
(
  max(att)
  for dt in ([hour_no_1_2013-01-21], [hour_no_2_2013-01-21],
             [hour_no_1_2013-01-22], [hour_no_2_2013-01-22])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c72e/6)

Or you can use dynamic sql to generate the sql statement at run-time. The dynamic version of the query is:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols 
  = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME('Hour_No_'+hr+'_'++convert(nvarchar(10), dt, 120)) 
           from stud
           group by hr, dt
           order by dt, hr
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT sname,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select sname, 
                  ''hour_no_''+hr+''_''+convert(nvarchar(10), dt, 120) dt,
                  att
                from stud
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(att)
                for dt in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c72e/9).

Both give the result:

```
| SNAME | HOUR_NO_1_2013-01-21 | HOUR_NO_2_2013-01-21 | HOUR_NO_1_2013-01-22 | HOUR_NO_2_2013-01-22 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Abi |                    a |                    p |                   ml |                   od |
|  bala |                    p |                    a |                   od |                   ml |
```

Comment: @user1999109 You are welcome. If this answer or any answer to your questions are helpful, then be sure to accept it via the checkmark to the left of it. It will help future visitors and you will get site rep for accepting.