# Increment Days in SQL query

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, increment

I am trying to write a query that will output the following table:

```
|Day_0_Revenue|Day_1_Revenue|Day_2_Revenue|....|Day_90_Revenue|
```

The data looks like the following table. Each day will have multiple values, and I want to sum the revenue for each day. Day 0 is 11/1.

```
|Date|Revenue|
11/1    5
11/2    3
11/3    5
11/3    7
11/4    8
11/5    8
11/5    12
11/6    7
```

I believe this is simple to do if the table I want is vertical. The reason I want to output horizontally is because I will fill the table vertically with other dates. My main question is how to increment the day value without writing a really long SELECT clause? I'm not sure if I can write a loop that will have something like Day+1 until Day=90...

Comment: what sql engine you are using?

Comment: I use SLQLite. I am more interested in the logic rather than the exact syntax.

Comment: I don't know if this works in sqllite, but in mssql I would do SELECT SUM(revenue) FROM table GROUP BY day

Comment: Hi Perry. Yes, that works, but it produces a vertically oriented table. I want the format to be horizontally oriented.

Comment: In SQL Server you can PIVOT a query - perhaps this assists:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529215/sql-pivot-table-with-three-cross-tab-and-multiple-columns-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in SQLite alone.

The easiest way would be to just use `GROUP BY day` to create a vertically oriented table, and then reorder the cells when you are displaying them.

If you really must get a horizontally oriented table from the database, you have to create the query dynamically:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM MyTable WHERE Date = '11/1') AS Day_0_Revenue,
       (SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM MyTable WHERE Date = '11/2') AS Day_1_Revenue,
       (SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM MyTable WHERE Date = '11/3') AS Day_2_Revenue,
       ...
```

You have to do this in whatever programming language you are using to access the database:

```py
sql = "SELECT"
for i in range(90):
    sql += " (SELECT SUM(Revenue) FROM MyTable" +
           " WHERE Date = '%s') AS Day_%d_Revenue," % (dates[i], i)
sql = sql[:-1] # remove last comma
cursor = db.execute(sql)
```